# CSS Margins Auto not Centering Floated Element

Tags: css, css-float, margins

I am having a problem centering a div element. The div element that I am trying to center has the following styles applied to it:

```
width: 60%;
float:right;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
min-width: 300px;
```

The only parent tag is the body tag which has the following styles applied to it:

```
width:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Instead of being centered, the element is aligned to the right. I previously had the element set to "float:left" and I didn't have a problem centering it, but when I changed it to "float:right" the element was no longer centered.

Comment: I think for `margin: auto` to work, the parent has to have a defined width, not an adjusted width like `100%`.

Comment: I updated my post, also, my body's width was set to 100% before I changed the float direction and it worked fine.

Comment: This is your CSS interpreted, but with no real changes: http://jsfiddle.net/aXAt7/

Comment: And `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/aXAt7/1/

Comment: And no `float`: http://jsfiddle.net/aXAt7/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to remove the `float:right`

Comment: why are you needing a float on this object?

Comment: Because I wanted content that was farther down in the HTML to display to the left of element.

Comment: well on that note what I would recommend putting both divs inside a container div and then center that container div. something like: `<div id="container'><div id="left-stuff"></div><div id="right-stuff"></div></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float: right;` from the styles.